# Union boolean object keeping substraction

Tags: modeling, modifiers, boolean-modifier, blenderkit

[image: Original model]

I want to upload my model to Blenderkit but it seems like it's required to be a single model, not a collection. There's a lot of boolean substraction (I used Bool tool). However when using union or joining it all substracted objects become unsubstracted.

[image: After union or join]

How do I make it a single object but also work with boolean substraction? I imagine I have to smoothen it somehow without retaining object info but I'm unsure how.

Comment: You'll need to apply all the modifiers before joining seperate objects into one.

Comment: @JonhEason would you like to make this an answer so I dont accept my one?

Comment: Now done thanks. You can delete yours if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to apply all the modifiers on every object before joining all your objects together. Hover over the modifier panel and hit <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to appy it or use the drop-down on the Modifier panel.
There's also a built-in addon which adds buttons above the modifier panel to apply all modifiers to the selected object at once:

[image]

[image]

I also put all the modifier objects into their own collection so that you can delete them all at once if required.